# how to understand the following 'os.path.join' python command?

Tags: python

I have a snippet like the following.

```
out_dir = os.path.join( dir, "myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']) )
```

I understand os.path.join is used to join one or more path components intelligently. So does that mean "myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']) is also a path component? Why would that be? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: It's just a string. Look up [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: `"myfile-{0}".format(x)` is conceptually the same as `"myfile-" + str(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze your question:

```
out_dir = os.path.join( dir, "myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']) )
```

What you already know is: `out_dir` is a variable name, `os.path.join` is a method that creates a directory path out of two (or more) strings.
What you're not completely sure about are the arguments of the method: `dir` being some variable declared before is also clear to you, but the expression `"myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID'])` is little confusing to you.
`myfile-{0}"` is a string and and one can call the method `format` on strings, the zero in the braces `{0}` is replaced by the first argument, and if there were `{1}` it would be replaced by a second argument. The return value of `os.environ['JOB_ID']` is inserted in place of `{0}`.

Let's say the return value is 1, so this would produce the string `"myfile-1"`. And let's say the value of `dir` is `"/path/to/the/directory"`. Then the variable `out_dir` is assigned the value `"/path/to/the/directory/myfile-1"`. Pay attention to the slash `/`. `os.path.join` creates the path to the file taking care of the directory separator.

That means  `"myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID'])` is also a path component.

Comment: I know you already answered this question. But somehow I got the following error:  out_dir = os.path.join(dir, "myfile-{0}".format(os.environ['JOB_ID']))
  File "/apps/x86_64/python/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'JOB_ID'
Do you happen to know why?

Comment: `os.environ['JOB_ID']` is trying to get the environment variable JOB_ID.  It has to be declared before the python script runs. You can run the command `env` in the bash and see if JOB_ID exists.

Comment: Please help me with the following code

    data_path = os.path.join(os.environ['DATA_PATH'], 'MovieLens')
    movies_filename = 'movies.csv'
    ratings_filename = 'ratings.csv'

Problem is I don't know how to set `['DATA_PATH']` ? It turns out that it is an `environment variable`. So I set an `environment variable` in my `Windows10` but still i am getting the same `KeyError`. I am running a Notebook file from this location `F:\Recommendation Systems\Practice\movie_recommender`.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ORxA.png